# Why does Chroma DB crash with "illegal instruction" in this python:3.10-slim container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry, chromadb

I am using [Chroma DB](https://docs.trychroma.com/) (0.4.8) in a Python 3.10 Flask REST API application. The application runs well on local developer machines (including Windows and OS X machines).

I am using the multi-stage `Dockerfile` below to package the application in an image based on `python:3.10-slim` (Debian 12 Bookworm). Images are built on **Github Actions** using the [`google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun) action:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim as base

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# -------------------------------------

FROM base as builder

ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.6

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --fix-missing build-essential

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

COPY pyproject.toml ./

COPY chat_api ./chat_api
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && \
    poetry install --only=main --no-root && \
    poetry build

# -------------------------------------

FROM base as final

COPY --from=builder /app/.venv ./.venv
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN ./.venv/bin/pip install *.whl
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

As I am using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) 1.6 to install the Python packages, here are the dependency specifications from my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
flask = "^2.3.3"
langchain = "^0.0.279"
flask-api = "^3.1"
openai = "0.27.8"
chromadb = "0.4.8"
tiktoken = "^0.4.0"
flask-sqlalchemy = "^3.0.5"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.20"
pymysql = "^1.1.0"
google-cloud-logging = "^3.6.0"
flask-httpauth = "^4.8.0"
flask-cors = "^4.0.0"
gunicorn = "^21.2.0"
flask-migrate = "^4.0.4"
cryptography = "^41.0.3"
```

When I run the image in Google Cloud Run aor on a dev machine, the application loads successfully. However, as soon as a call is made to an endpoint that imports `chromadb`, the process crashes with this traceback:

```
[ERROR] Worker (pid:3) was sent SIGILL!
Uncaught signal: 4, pid=3, tid=3, fault_addr=3.
Extension modules: google._upb._message, grpc._cython.cygrpc, charset_normalizer.md, _cffi_backend, markupsafe._speedups, sqlalchemy.cyextension.collections, sqlalchemy.cyextension.immutabledict, sqlalchemy.cyextension.processors, sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy, sqlalchemy.cyextension.util, greenlet._greenlet, yaml._yaml, pydantic.typing, pydantic.errors, pydantic.version, pydantic.utils, pydantic.class_validators, pydantic.config, pydantic.color, pydantic.datetime_parse, pydantic.validators, pydantic.networks, pydantic.types, pydantic.json, pydantic.error_wrappers, pydantic.fields, pydantic.parse, pydantic.schema, pydantic.main, pydantic.dataclasses, pydantic.annotated_types, pydantic.decorator, pydantic.env_settings, pydantic.tools, pydantic, numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, multidict._multidict, yarl._quoting_c, aiohttp._helpers, aiohttp._http_writer, aiohttp._http_parser, aiohttp._websocket, frozenlist._frozenlist, numexpr.interpreter (total: 56)
  File "/app/.venv/bin/gunicorn", line 8 in <module>
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67 in run
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236 in run
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72 in run
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202 in run
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 571 in manage_workers
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 642 in spawn_workers
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609 in spawn_worker
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142 in init_process
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126 in run
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70 in run_for_one
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 32 in accept
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135 in handle
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 178 in handle_request
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213 in __call__
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190 in wsgi_app
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484 in full_dispatch_request
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469 in dispatch_request
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_httpauth.py", line 174 in decorated
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redacted/routes.py", line 39 in messages_post
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redacted/logic.py", line 25 in __init__
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redacted/logic.py", line 40 in _load_vector_store
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 119 in __init__
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 143 in Client
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 247 in instance
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/api/segment.py", line 82 in __init__
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 188 in require
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 244 in instance
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 293 in get_class
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126 in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050 in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/manager/local.py", line 13 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/vector/local_persistent_hnsw.py", line 9 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/vector/local_hnsw.py", line 21 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1176 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
Current thread 0x00003ef4e1198b80 (most recent call first):
Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction
```

The last coherent (to me) line in the traceback points to line 21 in `chromadb/segment/impl/vector/local_hnsw.py` which only contains `import hnswlib`. I deduce that this is a failure in the installation of the [`chroma-hnswlib`](https://pypi.org/project/chroma-hnswlib/) package.

In the image's virtual environment `.venv/lib/python-3.10/site_packages` folder, I see the package as the folder `chroma_hnswlib-0.7.2.dist-info` and an adjacent file called `hnswlib.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

**My question is - Why is my image failing to correctly install `chroma-hnswlib` and how can I fix this?**

**UPDATE:** I have modified my `Dockerfile` so that it now uses a single stage. This means `build-essentials` packages are now present in the resulting image. When I run the new image on my Windows machine (AMD Ryzen 7), the crash is no longer present. When I run the image in Google Cloud Run, the crash is reproduced.

**UPDATE 2:** Up until now the images I've used were built in Github Actions. I've made the experiment of building an image on my dev machine and deploying directly to Cloud Run - It works. I'm now investigating which type of CPU GH Actions is running the build on.

Comment: I guess that image runs debian 12 bookworm? "_The application runs well on local developer machines_" Good. Recommend you get it running well under an interactive python:3.10-slim-bookworm ssh / bash prompt. Then compare details of that environment with the docker environment. Verify they're both 64-bit, both little endian, same CPU family, same .so library binary versions, that sort of thing.

Comment: @J_H thank you. I think it is Debian "bookworm". I can add that having converted my `Dockerfile` to a single stage, things seem to work fine. I think perhaps something in `build-essential` is essential not only for building but also at runtime?

Comment: "Illegal instruction" typically means you're running code compiled for a different CPU than you actually have. It doesn't mean code is _incorrectly_ installed; more, that your CPU is older than what the person who compiled the binaries had configured as the minimum target (or using an emulation layer like Apple's Rosetta, which doesn't support a lot of more obscure Intel/AMD instructions). This is a place where a Linux distro like Arch that can be configured with details of your specific CPU to recompile _everything_ for that target can come in handy.

Comment: (...of course, recompiling the world is slow, and everyone having different locally-built binaries poses challenges for distro-level QA, but that's what you pay to have things built for the specific hardware you're going to run on)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you. I will try and understand what the CPU is when running in Cloud Run to see if I can adapt the build to it.

Comment: For a cloud environment, there's also the potential that some CPU instructions features are masked out for security reasons (f/e, if they're known to be usable to launch a speculative execution attack). Anyhow -- I'd suggest attaching a C debugger like gdb to the process and inspecting the instruction it breaks on; checking where the issue is triggered will tell you which exact library it is that's causing the problem, thus exactly which thing needs to be compiled for a different CPU.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've now realized that when I build the image on my dev machine and deploy to Cloud Run, it runs fine. When it's built using Github Actions, it breaks. I'll try to compare filesysstems b/w two such images to see what might explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: If one is building from source and the other is using binaries, that would explain it. You could figure that out from logs rather than needing to compare the resulting filesystems -- working back from a .so file to the details of how it was compiled is not always straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
FROM base as final

COPY --from=builder /app/.venv ./.venv
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
...
```

Prefer:

```
FROM builder as final

COPY ...
```

The trouble was that dynamically linked *.so libraries
were being installed in a location that you neglected to copy over,
leading to lossage.

Symlink `.venv` to `/app` if need be.
Or COPY it.
Or arrange for the relevant `/app` directory to appear in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thank you @J_H. I'd still like to know exactly which dynamically linked libraries are missing so I can cherry-pick them into my final stage. The motivation for the multi-stage build is to minimize the size of the image.

Comment: A library _not being found_ typically causes a different error. Do you know the mechanism by which it's turning into illegal-instruction errors for the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past my `illegal instruction` errors with Chroma by setting the environment variable `HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE=1` before running `pip install chromadb`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/blob/3f3429661187e4c24a490a0f148fc6bc89042b3d/setup.py#L86-L87), this removes use of the `-march=native` compiler flag. As @CharlesDuffy indicates in a comment above, `illegal instruction` indicates a difference in CPU features between where you built it and where you're running it. So this workaround, if not ideal, at least makes sense.

In my case, I'm building on AWS CodeBuild and running in Lambda. One idea to (maybe?) ensure the CPUs are the same is the new [support for using Lambda runtimes in CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/lambda.html), but you can't use `docker` commands there (a further suggestion is to use `podman` instead—maybe I'll try it sometime, but for now ‍♂️, things are working and it all seems fine).